# Unable to ping from devices connected to AP to devices connected to Home Gateway in CISCO Packet Tracer

Tags: routing, wireless-access-point, gateway, cisco-packet-tracer

Packet Tracer Design shown here:

[image: Topology Overview]

I am trying to ping the devices connected to the Home Gateway from the Tablets connected to the AP. The TabletPC connected to the home gateway allows me to view the IoT devices on an IoT manager application. This same application can not connect to the devices from the TabletPCs connected to the AP.

I know this is because the AP is connected to the network `192.168.10.0`. The home gateway is giving the devices IP addresses on the `192.168.25.x` network.

My problem is I can't figure out any way to allow the tablets on the AP to communicate with the devices on the home gateway.

The response from ping shows:

> 200.100.0.1: Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: I can't see anything saying I have wireless isolation enabled. But I can't access the devices on the IoT manager application from the tablets.

Comment: I will try that, not exactly sure how to go about doing it though.

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately. Can't seem to find any subnet settings